# Compute difference between values in dataframe column

Tags: python, dataframe

i have this dataframe:

```
a   b   c   d
4   7   5   12
3   8   2   8
1   9   3   5
9   2   6   4
```

i want the column 'd' to become the difference between n-value of column a and n+1 value of column 'a'.
I tried this but it doesn't run:

```
for i in data.index-1:
data.iloc[i]['d']=data.iloc[i]['a']-data.iloc[i+1]['a']
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: data['d'].iloc[i] will work.

Comment: already tried but it doesn't work, this is the advice:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)

Comment: are you using pandas?

Comment: yes, i m using pandas for dataframe

Comment: Ok and did you use json_normalize(data) for using your dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what you want is diff.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"a":[4,3,1,9]})
df["d"] = df["a"].diff(periods=-1)

print(df)
```

## Output

```
   a    d
0  4  1.0
1  3  2.0
2  1 -8.0
3  9  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

lets try simple way:

```
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'a':[2,4,8,15]})
diff=[]
for i in range(len(df)-1):
    diff.append(df['a'][i+1]-df['a'][i])
diff.append(np.nan)
df['d']=diff
print(df)

    a   d
0   2   2.0
1   4   4.0
2   8   7.0
3   15  NaN
```